# 301 redirect with cut last word

Tags: .htaccess

I want redirect or delete last phrase from url with .htaccess:

```
https://example.com/en/word1/word2/random-word-with-numbers/lang-en-GB
```

to

```
https://example.com/en/word1/word2/random-word-with-numbers
```

What I shall do? I tried but doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^word2/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+/word2/[^/.]+)/.+$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Link [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=f7ab0593-2079-5081-bdb9-e3013793c4ff) to show that @Croises answer does work.